# Getting data from second multidimensional array into datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I need to get a row from another `array` into my `datatable`

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
      "data": ex1,ex2,
      "destroy": true,
       columns: [
          { ex1: "Name" },
          { ex1: "Position" },
          { ex1: "Office" },
          { ex1: "Extn." },
          { ex1: "Start date" },
          { ex1: "Salary" },
          { ex2: "article_id" }
       ]
   });
 }
```

I should be able to connect the `databases` using "article_id" since they both have it and the values are the same, but how do I use it in a `datatable`?

```
if ex1[0]['article_id'] === ex2[0]['article_id'] --
```

put `ex2[0]['article_id']` into datatable.

Comment: build your data outside your datatable function

Comment: @madalinivascu how do I do that?

Comment: you use array/object maipulations